# Extension method not working in silverlight windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I wrote one extension method FindAll for IEnumerable to filter based on the predicate condition. for common to both Array and List. because In sil

the code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> tCollection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
     if (null == tCollection) yield return default(T);
     using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = tCollection.GetEnumerator())
     {
          if (!iterator.MoveNext())
          {
              yield return default(T);
              yield break;
          }

          do
          {
              if (predicate(iterator.Current))
                 yield return iterator.Current;
          }
          while (iterator.MoveNext());
     }
}
```

it does not work for me when I am calling..

```
    List<string> strings = new List<string> { "Kumaran", "Raj", "Kannan", "Karthi", "Gopal" };

    IEnumerable<string> str = strings.FindAll(item => item.StartsWith("K"));
```

Can I know why it is not working for me in my application.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, could you elaborate on what you mean by "it does not work for me"?

Comment: Why would you want to yield a single element (the default) if the list is empty or the reference is null - but not if the list has entries, with none of them matching the predicate? And why aren't you just using the built-in `Enumerable.Where` method?

Comment: The reason you're seeing different behaviour on Silverlight is that your method wouldn't get called at all on desktop .NET, because `List<T>` already has a `FindAll` method (which isn't broken like this one is).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my guess (although it could be that you haven't shown us all your actual relevant code).

You place break point somewhere in your FindAll method.  Then you run the line:-

```
IEnumerable<string> str = strings.FindAll(item => item.StartsWith("K"));
```

but your break point isn't hit, right?

However this is correct.  Your FindAll method will not actually be invoked until the first call to `MoveNext` of an enumerator aquired from the `IEnumerable` in `str`.  So if you followed your code with say a `foreach` on `str` you should see code start to happen.

BTW, your implementation looks a little suspect, surely you would not want to an enumerable containing single default value to be returned when the source is null or empty?

In fact if you really want to return a filtered set from an `IEnumerable<T>` why don't you just use the Linq `Where` extension method instead.  On the other hand if you are trying to create an implementation of FindAll as found in the full .NET API for a List then you ought to be returning a `List<T>` as well.

I suspect that what you really should be doing is adding this `using` to your code file:-

```
using System.Linq;
```

then you can use:-

```
IEnumerable<string> str = strings.Where(item => item.StartsWith("K"));
```

and if you really need the `FindAll` feature that returns a `List<T>` then:-

```
List<string> str = strings.Where(item => item.StartsWith("K")).ToList();
```